# Custom Character Class in Perl 5.018

Tags: regex, perl, unicode

I have a parsing environment (Marpa::R2::Scanless) that needs to use single Perl regexp character classes to control tokenizing. I've got something to tokenize that doesn't seem to fit any of the existing character classes. So, after digging around in the perlunicode docs, I've come up with the following code, except it doesn't work as expected. I expect to see a row of dots interspersed with all the non-alphanumerics (except parens). Instead, I get a runtime error about not being able to find the character class.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use 5.018;
use utf8;

local $| = 1;

for my $i (map { chr($_) } 32 .. 127) {
    if ($i =~ /\p{Magic::Wow}/) {
        print $i;
    }
    else {
        print ".";
    }
}

package Magic;

sub Wow {
    return <<'MAGIC';
+utf8::Assigned
-utf8::Letter
-utf8::Number
-0028
-0029
MAGIC
}

1;
```

Any hints, tips, tricks, or suggestions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Name the sub `IsWow` and the property `Magic::IsWow`.

Quoting [*User-Defined Character Properties* in perlunicode](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlunicode.html#User-Defined-Character-Properties):

> You can define your own binary character properties by defining subroutines whose names begin with "In" or "Is".

Comment: Thanks. It's amazing how little snippets like that can slip through the cracks in the excitement.